# Securing PHP XML Web Service AJAX

Tags: php, xml, ajax, web-services, security

I have an XML web service that javascript calls are made using jQuery.  This can output JSON or XML based on the parameters input.

Is there a way to stop someone from easily just finding the URL of the AJAX call and then loading that into a cURL script and parsing the data.

The users to the site do not authenticate but open to some creative methods!  As it is AJAX is the user-agent set or can I block it using an .htaccess file in any way?

Comment: Nope, it's sad but there is no way.

Comment: Even if you get some lame protection, anyone who will have interest in your data, may come here on stackoverflow and get detailed answer with working code. Because on this shameless site no one cares for the fellow webmaster if there is a possibility to snatch a few reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Ajax requests send the header `X_REQUESTED_WITH = XMLHttpRequest`.
So as an extra measure check for the `X_REQUESTED_WITH` header

But this still won't stop people finding the url's and running them if they know what they're doing.

Comment: But quite a nice simple thing to deter the simple person?

Answer (score 0):

There's no real protection in this case, since everything the browser sends to the server can be faked.

One Idea would be to send a (session-)cookie to the client with some encrypted data. When the Ajax-Request is made, the browser sends back the cookie-data. Your php-script that is  generating the ajax response could check the cookie-data before actually sending the response. 
But this just ensures, that the "outer" HTML page is called before the "inner" Ajax-Request.

Comment: Of course it does - at least if you spend one minute to think about the data you encrypt (User-Agent, Timestamp, Client-IP, Remote Port...)